# Xpath: get last element of branch

Tags: html, xpath

Is any solution how get last N-grandchildren if know his N-grandparent. Its like: I know start point of branch and I need take last element of this branch.

```
<div class="start-parent">
    ...
        ...         // a lot of other elements
            ...
                <div class="last-child end-of-branch"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you html looks like this:

```
<div class="start-parent">
  <div class="first-child of-branch"></div>
  <div class="second-child of-branch">
      <div class="a grand-child of-branch"></div>
      <div class="last grand-child end-of-branch"></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="last-child end-of-branch"></div>
</div>
```

This expression:

```
//div[@class="start-parent"]//*/*[last()]/@class
```

selects

```
last grand-child end-of-branch
```

while this one

```
//div[@class="start-parent"]/div[1]/following-sibling::div[last()]/@class
```

selects

```
last-child end-of-branch
```

Comment: yeah. but my problem that: I dont know how many parents between grandparent and grandchild

Comment: @Mot1k The code doesn't require that you know that number; it always selects either the last child or the last grandchild